# Create action after multiple clicks on UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton

I want to create an action after the user has clicked on the same button multiple times. I don't know how to implement this and I haven't found anything that could help me yet.

Comment: Give us a tiny bit of context. Have you already managed to hook up a button to an action method in Interface Builder?

Comment: Do you mean for example double click? Or counting the clicks on that button.

Comment: I have a button in my storyboard and I want to create an action after multiple clicks on the button.

Comment: Lets say I want to create an action after the user has clicked 10 times on the button @Tarek

Comment: Then you need to write some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of implementation file create a count variable

```
@interface yourViewController (){
    int buttonCount;
}
```

initialize somewhere (for ex. `viewDidLoad`)

```
buttonCount = 0;
```

in your IBAction (assuming you've linked your UIButton to an IBAction)

```
- (IBAction)yourButton:(id)sender{

   buttonCount++;

   if (buttonCount >= 10){ // button clicked 10 or more times

      //do something

      buttonCount = 0;//if you need to reset after action
   }

}
```

Comment: My app crashes after implementing this code

Comment: OK, well whats in the crash log

Comment: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: I also added the action after 10 clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this a number of ways.

One would be to "make your own button" and subclass UIButton and try to override the gesture recognizer.  This probably would be very hacky and unclean.

Another way to "make your own button" would be to make a UIView that has a TapGestureRecognizer with numberOfTapsRequired set to the number of taps that you want.

I think the best way for your purposes (probably) is to have a global variable in your private @interface that you put above the top of your implementation file (like so) and then increment it every time the button is tapped, and then reset it when the action occurs.

```
 @interface YourViewController (){
      NSInteger buttonTaps;
 }

 @end

 @implementation YourViewController
 -(IBAction)buttonTap:(id)sender
 {
    if (buttonTaps < numberYouWant) 
       buttonTaps++;
    else
       [self theNameOfTheMethodThatImplementsTheThingsYouWantToOccur]
 }


 -(void) theNameOfTheMethodThatImplementsTheThingsYouWantToOccur
  {
    // perform your action
    buttonTaps = 0; // reset counter
  }

 @end
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

I just want to note I would probably subclass UIView as it is the cleanest way to implement this and the most individuated, and I think would be a good programming challenge for you to implement once you get the functionality you want working.

Answer (score 0):

How about UITapGestureRecognizer?

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {     
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
    //handle code here
  } 
}
```

That will handle the multiple taps for you. Here are the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITapGestureRecognizer) for you so you get to know about it.

If you Google the method name +tutorial, you will probably find a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidLoad:`

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(yourTapHandler:)];
[self.yourButton addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 10;
```

Then in `yourTapHandler:` do whatever you want to happen after the taps:

```
-(void)yourTapHandler:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Whats my TapHandler? @hw731

Comment: @user2654446 - It's just a method you write that will be called when the button is tapped 10 times. You can name it whatever you want.

Comment: @user2654446 - Sorry I think I was unclear in my first answer. Edited to fix.

Comment: No problem appreciate the help. Should I replace, where it says "the button" in the code, with what my button is named? @hw731

Comment: @user2654446 - Yes, absolutely.

Comment: When I do I receive an error "Property "MyButtonName" not found on object of type "MainViewcontroller""

Comment: @user2654446 - Because your button isn't named 'MyButtonName'. I can't see your code so I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(yourTapHandler:)];
[self.done addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 10;

Comment: my button is named "done"

Comment: Then the second line of code will look like this: `[self.done addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];`

Comment: Thats what I did from the beginning and thats when I receive the error.

Comment: @user2654446 - You're going to have to edit your question with some of your code.

Comment: Just FYI @hw731 this will only work if the taps are in quick succession. I obviously don't know what OP wants to do but if the taps are spread out over a longer duration this won't work

Answer (score 0):

Declare an instance variable 'count' in your view controller class. Connect the button to an action method either using XIB or in your controller via code using `addTarget:action: forControlEvents:`. The method will get called every time the user clicks the button. Increment the count by 1 each time. Check if(count == 10) or any number for that matter, in that case, call any method or execute any code you want.